# How to use GoogleFonts in custom text Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've multiple text in app with different `fontFamily` So I've created a custom text class but how to use `GoogleFonts` in custom text class? So that I can easily use `fontWeight`, `color`, `fontSize` of `GoogleFonts`.

**Here is my `CustomText` class**

```
 class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double? size;
  final FontWeight? fontWeight;
  final Color? color;
  final double? wordSpacing;
  final VoidCallback? onClick;

  const CustomText({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.size,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.color,
    this.wordSpacing,
    this.onClick,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: onClick == null
          ? Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: size ?? 14,
                fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.w500,
                color: color ?? Colors.grey,
                wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
              ),
            )
          : TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onClick!.call();
              },
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: size ?? 16,
                  fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.w500,
                  color: color ?? Colors.grey,
                  wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xfff00B074),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontFamily: 'Barlow-Medium',
              color: Color(0xff464255)),
        ),
      ),
      home: CustomTextDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTextDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomText(
        text: "Custom Text Demo",
        googleFontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato(
          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
          fontSize: 22.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double size;
  final FontWeight fontWeight;
  final Color color;
  final double wordSpacing;
  final VoidCallback onClick;
  final String fontFamily; /* Add this Font Family param */
  final TextStyle googleFontFamily;

  const CustomText({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    this.size,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.color,
    this.wordSpacing,
    this.onClick,
    this.fontFamily,
    this.googleFontFamily,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return onClick == null
        ? Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Text(
              text,
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: googleFontFamily,
              // TextStyle(
              //     fontSize: size ?? 14,
              //     fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.w500,
              //     color: color ?? Colors.grey,
              //     wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
              //     fontFamily: 'Roboto'), /* Add this Font Family param */
            ),
          )
        /* 
        Wrapping with Align mimics textAlign behaviour
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: googleFontFamily,
             
            ),
          )
           */
        : TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              onClick.call();
            },
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: size ?? 16,
                fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.w500,
                color: color ?? Colors.grey,
                wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use `fontFamily` through `GoogleFonts`. How to use it?

Comment: GoogleFonts.lato ***Lato*** itself is a font family

Comment: `TextAlign.center` is not working

Comment: Either You can wrap your Text with an Align widget and use alignment property to get the textAlign behavior
or you can also wrap your text with Container and provide ***width*** width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

Comment: already tried with align

Comment: Please check above edited code in CustomText class. I have mentioned both with Align widget and also with Container widget, both works fine for me. Please try this.

Comment: Try with Container widget. Please refer above edited code wrapped with Container

Comment: Please try above edited code with Align widget

Comment: Sorry I was busy at that moment ,I'll try your code and let you now soon.

Comment: No problem, Please try and let me know

Comment: As I'm new in flutter, I've a question that when `Text` widget has all its properties, then what is the use of creating our `Text` widget?

Comment: This error occurs because your Text property does not contain full-width that's why your TextAlign not working. To solve textAlign not working flutter just use Align Widget or Just use Wrap your Text widget to SizedBox or Container and give all of width.

Comment: yeah I got your point ,but I've a question..

Comment: Yes, Without specifying width textAlign property doesn't work. By using Align widget The alignment property describes a point in the child 's coordinate system and a different point in the coordinate system of this widget.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got it right, as I never tried to apply as a use-case, but I think you can combine by using the `getFont` and checking before using its implementation.

```
 class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double? size;
  final String googleFont;
  final FontWeight? fontWeight;
  final Color? color;
  final double? wordSpacing;
  final VoidCallback? onClick;
  TextStyle? myTextStyle;

  CustomText({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.size,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.color,
    this.googleFont = '',
    this.wordSpacing,
    this.onClick,
  }) : super(key: key);




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   

    myTextStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize: size ?? 14,
                fontWeight: fontWeight ?? FontWeight.w500,
                color: color ?? Colors.grey,
                wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
              );

    return Container(
      child: onClick == null
          ? Text(
              text,
              style: googleFont.isEmpty ? myTextStyle:GoogleFonts.getFont(
                googleFont, textStyle: myTextStyle),
            )
          : TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onClick!.call();
              },
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: googleFont.isEmpty ? myTextStyle : GoogleFonts.getFont(
                googleFont, textStyle: myTextStyle),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```